# implicit cast yields incorrect result

Tags: c#

Would you consider this to be a bug, or to be expected behaviour?

Consider the following

```
  1 * (2/(1+2))

  equals 0

  1 * ((double)2/(1+2))

  equals 0.6667
```

Comment: It's OK, cause there is implicit cast to int in first row. If you wanna to work with double you can use double number format `1 * (2.0/(1+2))
`

Comment: @user854301: it looks like something the compiler should be able to work out.

Comment: its expected behavoir as long as you understand type conversions :) For many newbies its a confusion. Always specify cast :)

Comment: There's **no "implicit cast"** in the first row. In the first case, the addition `(1+2)` is an addition of `int`s yielding an `int`, then `2/3` is a division of `int`s yielding an `int`, finally `1*0` is a multiplication of `int`s yielding an `int`. In the second case, last row, `1+2` is again an `int` operation. But then `2.0 / 3` is an expression with a `double` and an `int`. But since there's an implicit conversion from `int` to `double` (and only that way), it becomes `2.0 / 3.0`, and we have a floating-point division. Finally, in `1 * 0.6667`, the `1` gets "promoted" to `1.0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a bug. Arithmetic operations where all operands are `int` yield an `int` as result.
This is also [documented in the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3b1ff23f%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

> When you divide two integers, the result is always an integer. For example, the result of 7 / 3 is 2. To determine the remainder of 7 / 3, use the remainder operator (%). To obtain a quotient as a rational number or fraction, give the dividend or divisor type float or type double. You can do this implicitly by expressing the dividend or divisor as a decimal by putting a digit to the right of the decimal point

Comment: @sgtz: It is the same in C, C++, Java etc.

Answer (score 1):

It is ok, since you have used ints in your expression.
You can use double operands instead of cast:

```
1d * (2d/(1d+2d))
```

Here is link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/678hzkk9(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You should use double/float numbers if you wanna to have result in this format:

```
1 * (2.0/(1+2))
```

or

```
1 * (2f/(1+2))
```

or

```
1 * (2d/(1+2))
```